Weird issue with my code - says that 1 positional argument was given even though I did not give any
A function in my code takes zero positional arguments. I called the function WITH zero positional arguments but python decided that for some reason it had one positional argument and now it's throwing an error!
Code:
(I defined the function at line 31, called it at line 86)
import time
import os

# colors class, used for coloring the printed text
class colors:
    yellow = '\033[93m'
    gray = '\033[90m'
    cyan = '\033[96m'
    green = '\033[92m'
    endc = '\033[0m'
    bold = "\033[1m"
    ul = "\033[4m"
    red = "\033[31m"
    blue = "\033[34m"
    orange = "\033[42m\033[34m\033[1m"
    purple = "\033[35m"
    itl = "\033[3m"

# typing animation
def typing(text, wpm=300):
    cps = wpm/12
    for letter in text:
        print(letter, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(1/cps)


# checks coordinates and provides response based on it
class CoordinateManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self = self
    def coordinateChecker():
        global coordinates
        DTCC = {
            "left" : [-1, 0],
            "right" : [1, 0],
            "forwards" : [0, 1],
            "backwards" : [0, -1]
        }
        # DTCC means "direction to coordinate change"
        coordinateChange = DTCC.get(direction)
        if not(coordLimits[0] >= (coordinates[0] + coordinateChange[0]) >= 0 and coordLimits[1] >= (coordinates[1] + coordinateChange[1]) >= 0):
            print("You ran onto a wall")
            return
        else:
            coordinates = [coordinates[0]+coordinateChange[0], coordinates[1]+coordinateChange[1]]


cm = CoordinateManager()
instructions = list(open("escapeInstructions.txt", "r"))
for line in instructions:
    line = f"{colors.cyan}{line}{colors.endc}"
    typing(line)

input(f"\n{colors.yellow}Press {colors.bold}enter{colors.endc}{colors.yellow} when you are ready to continue: {colors.endc}\n")

story = list(open("escapeStory.txt", "r"))
for line in story:
    line = f"{colors.cyan}{line}{colors.endc}"
    typing(line)

input(f"\n{colors.yellow}Press {colors.bold}enter{colors.endc}{colors.yellow} when you are ready to continue: {colors.endc}")

typing("\n Pick a number from 1 to 4. Each of your teammates must pick a different number.")
typing("\n This will be your 'character number', and it is what the game will use to decide how you will be split when you must do so.")

while True:
    charNum = int(input())
    if charNum not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        print("The number you entered is invalid, please try again.")
        print("\n Enter a number from 1 to 4")
    else:
        typing(f"You chose character number {charNum}. Do you confirm this decision?")
        if "yes" in input("\n Type 'yes' and hit enter to confirm").lower():
            break
        else:
            print("Alright then. What character number do you choose?")
coordinates = [0, 0]
coordLimits = [5, 5]
typing("Start navigating the room by going either left, right, forwards or backwards.")
while True:
    print(f"Coordinates: {coordinates}")
    direction = input("Enter any one of the four directions (left, right, forwards, backwards) to move in that direction. To check your inventory, enter 'inventory': ")
    if direction.lower() not in ["left", "right", "forwards", "backwards", "inventory"]:
        continue
    if direction != "inventory":
        cm.coordinateChecker()
        continue

I tried checking both the calling of my function and the place where I made the function to check and yeah, it accepts 0 positional arguments and I gave 0 positional arguments.

TL;DR: typo in def coordinateChecker(): - you forgot self. If you don't want/need self, 1) think carefully about whether that method really belongs in the class, 2) consider using a classmethod or staticmethod

The issue here is in the coordinateChecker method within your CoordinateManager class. When you call this method, Python automatically passes the instance (self) as the first argument, but your method signature doesn't include this argument. Because of this Python is considering it as having one positional argument.
To fix this, you should include self as the first argument in your method definition and python will handle it.
